# Swift - Issue with data types

Tags: ios, swift

I am loading some data into NSUserDefaults on application startup and when the user views the according View loading the data out into a TableView. I'm having an issue with the data types though and always seem to get an error whichever way I try.

Where am I going wrong. I am skipping some code and only giving the important parts. I keep getting errors like "Can't assign Bool to AnyObject"

```
// startup function which loads the data
var categorys : [[String:Bool]] = [["All": true]]
for (index: String, category: JSON) in output {
    categorys.append([category["name"].string!: true])
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(categorys, forKey: "categorys")


// view controller

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var categorys: [[String:Bool]] = []

    func buildTableView() {
        if let categorys = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("categorys") {
            for category in categorys {
                self.categorys.append([category["name"] as! String: category["selected"] as! Bool])
            }
            // Was trying to just assign straight away but fails
            // self.categorys = categorys
        }
    }


// then later on I want to be able to do the following
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.categorys[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (self.categorys[indexPath.row]["selected"] as? Bool == true) {
            self.categorys[indexPath.row]["selected"] = "false"
        }
    }
}
```

I should probably also mention i was trying a different datatype before which is more logical for my usage but also had similar issues.

```
["name": [category["name"].string!, "selected": true]]
```

I should also mention this is data for my tableview and I want to update the boolean value for if the cell is selected to not.

Comment: On which line does this error occur?

Comment: In this example its on the self.categorys.append with the error of finding nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in the comment that you've got an error about "finding nil", but it's not really the same as an error about "Can't assign Bool to AnyObject"...

For your `nil` error, you have to replace those forced typecasts:

```
category["name"] as! String
```

with optional binding:

```
if let name = category["name"] as? String {

}
```

Now it will fail but not crash if a property is nil, and will properly append to the array of dictionaries:

```
let category = ["name":"me", "selected":true]

var categorys: [[String:Bool]] = []

if let name = category["name"] as? String, let selected = category["selected"] as? Bool {
    categorys.append([name:selected])
} else {
    // oops, a value was nil, handle the error
}
```

Same for your other operations, don't use forced casts:

```
if let myBool = self.categorys[indexPath.row]["selected"] where myBool == true {
    self.categorys[indexPath.row]["selected"] = false
}
```

*And since `self.categorys[indexPath.row]["selected"]` is a Bool type, don't assign a string like "false" but the actual `false` value.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Bool` in `NSUserDefaults`, you must use `setBool: forKey:` :

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "key")
```

otherwise it's problematic and you have to do workarounds, like storing the `Bool` in `NSNumber` or `String`.

Comment: As I want to store the data to whether or not the Cell in the TableView is checked, would it be better me to just use a NSNumber or String?

Comment: I would definitely go for `NSNumber` like this - `NSNumber(bool: true)`